# What are the tactics used to discover what kind of affiliate products will do well in your website?

Tags: marketing, affiliate

I'm starting to post some affiliate ads on my website. As it happens, I am not even close to making a sale.

- I'm not sure if the products I have chosen will appeal to the audience I have.
- I'm not sure if the volume of traffic is enough to support affiliate programs. I get about 8000-9000 visitors everyday. But since its growing constantly, thats not much of a worry.

But I'm surely struggling to figure out what kind of products to market? (its a techie site).

Is there a service/tool which can analyze the website and suggest what products will do well and what won't?

Answer (score 1):

ok, this is what i usually do:

set up adsense on your site, incl. channels. let it run for a couple of days so google gets a chance to target ads relevant for your audience.

now:

1. check the ads you get from google
2. check in your adsense account the different ad types you get (dating, technology, etc.)
3. measure which channels and what type of ads get you the most clicks
4. pick and choose your affiliate deals and programs according to those that got you the most clicks with google

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on niche. For example, if you've a recipe site then placing hosting ads or software ads is not going to be useful. In case of recipe site you have to choose the food niche ads. That way you'll be able to generate atleast few leads. Try to be more relevant with the ads. Don't put pizza ads on weight loss recipe site. This was just an example. In case of affiliate products you have to choose the relevant products to make *decent* sells. Minimize the banners and try to put relevant ads around your niche site.

In your case site is in tech niche. So you'll benefit if the ads are related to softwares, cloud apps and services. Take a look at some of the popular sites in your niche, observe their placements and the type of ads. Buysellads.com has lots of advertisers in tech niche. You can place those ads as they only place ads on publisher sites if the ads are relevant to niche. That way you don't have to do the work.